# Divide one cell into one separate heatmap/with multiple color code

Tags: r, layout, plot, ggplot2, heatmap

Sample data -

```
 Country segments variable  value
      US    A   Kerosene    16.09
      US    B   Kerosene    2.81
      US    C   Kerosene    -7.96
      US    D   Kerosene    25.76
      US    E   Kerosene    75.47
      US    A   Petrol  26.82
      US    B   Petrol  8.72
      US    C   Petrol  2.07
      US    D   Petrol  16
      US    E   Petrol  -11
      US    A   Edible Oil  4.02
      US    B   Edible Oil  10.6
      US    C   Edible Oil  49.05
      US    D   Edible Oil  16.07
      US    E   Edible Oil  51.87
      US    A   LPG -1.07
      US    B   LPG 49.19
      US    C   LPG 37.9
      US    D   LPG 33.05
      US    E   LPG 102
```

This is the data set for US, like that I have dataset of 14 other countries in the file. Now a days I make 15 separate heatmap in hierarchical approach. The x-axis is the variable and y-axis the segments and the heatmap with concern values based on each country.

What I was thinking is to make a single slide with all the countries as well. So the final result with be - y-axis same with the segments, x-axis with countries and each cell is a heat map with four different variable and corresponding value in single cell.

Any help will be of great- Any idea of how I can code and make a single cell to a heapmap with four different values and color code.Something like below - That will be an example of 8 countries and 4 segments with 4 variables.

[image: Something like below - That will be an example of 8 countries and 4 segments with 4 variables]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't provide a full reproducible example (or any code you've already tried), I made up some dummy data to show how you might do it.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

fake.df <- 
expand.grid(Country = c("US", "Canada", "Mexico"), 
            segments = LETTERS[1:5], 
            variable = c("Kerosene", "Petrol",
                         "Edible Oil", "LPG")) %>% 
  mutate(value = runif(length(Country), -20, 50))

fake.df.adj <- 
fake.df %>% 
  mutate(xadj = ifelse(variable %in% c("Kerosene", "Edible Oil"), -0.33/2,  0.33/2),
         yadj = ifelse(variable %in% c("Kerosene", "Petrol"),      0.33/2, -0.33/2),
         xpos = as.numeric(factor(Country))  + xadj,
         ypos = as.numeric(factor(segments)) + yadj)
```

The `mutate` code creates a box of adjustments around each center point you want to plot. For "Kerosene" and "Edible Oil", those tiles are shifted to the left by 1/3 of the space between each `Country` (so the center of each tile is -0.33/2); the others are shifted right. Same with the y adjustment, but up and down instead of left and right.

Then you convert your factors (`Country` and `segments`) to numeric positions and add them together.

---

```
fake.df.adj
```

> ```
>    Country segments   variable       value   xadj   yadj  xpos  ypos
> 1       US        A   Kerosene -11.8318607 -0.165  0.165 0.835 1.165
> 2   Canada        A   Kerosene  39.1181835 -0.165  0.165 1.835 1.165
> 3   Mexico        A   Kerosene  25.9354644 -0.165  0.165 2.835 1.165
> 4       US        B   Kerosene -19.3503525 -0.165  0.165 0.835 2.165
> 5   Canada        B   Kerosene -12.4459506 -0.165  0.165 1.835 2.165
> 6   Mexico        B   Kerosene   9.9017016 -0.165  0.165 2.835 2.165
> 7       US        C   Kerosene  37.9767562 -0.165  0.165 0.835 3.165
> 8   Canada        C   Kerosene   3.4687111 -0.165  0.165 1.835 3.165
> 9   Mexico        C   Kerosene   0.6280239 -0.165  0.165 2.835 3.165
> 10      US        D   Kerosene  43.4739464 -0.165  0.165 0.835 4.165
> 11  Canada        D   Kerosene   8.4671510 -0.165  0.165 1.835 4.165
> 12  Mexico        D   Kerosene  19.7357609 -0.165  0.165 2.835 4.165
> 13      US        E   Kerosene  -2.6120700 -0.165  0.165 0.835 5.165
> 14  Canada        E   Kerosene -10.6013792 -0.165  0.165 1.835 5.165
> 15  Mexico        E   Kerosene  -6.2059698 -0.165  0.165 2.835 5.165
> 16      US        A     Petrol  17.1079974  0.165  0.165 1.165 1.165
> 17  Canada        A     Petrol  46.8944785  0.165  0.165 2.165 1.165
> 18  Mexico        A     Petrol   9.3977815  0.165  0.165 3.165 1.165
> 19      US        B     Petrol  38.7547489  0.165  0.165 1.165 2.165
> 20  Canada        B     Petrol -14.4210703  0.165  0.165 2.165 2.165
> 21  Mexico        B     Petrol  32.5160861  0.165  0.165 3.165 2.165
> 22      US        C     Petrol  -1.3750645  0.165  0.165 1.165 3.165
> 23  Canada        C     Petrol  17.0540527  0.165  0.165 2.165 3.165
> 24  Mexico        C     Petrol -16.8449931  0.165  0.165 3.165 3.165
> 25      US        D     Petrol  33.8465349  0.165  0.165 1.165 4.165
> 26  Canada        D     Petrol  43.7369153  0.165  0.165 2.165 4.165
> 27  Mexico        D     Petrol  32.2145640  0.165  0.165 3.165 4.165
> 28      US        E     Petrol -13.1811532  0.165  0.165 1.165 5.165
> 29  Canada        E     Petrol  46.1913082  0.165  0.165 2.165 5.165
> 30  Mexico        E     Petrol  -7.5030316  0.165  0.165 3.165 5.165
> 31      US        A Edible Oil  36.1643957 -0.165 -0.165 0.835 0.835
> 32  Canada        A Edible Oil  26.9887728 -0.165 -0.165 1.835 0.835
> 33  Mexico        A Edible Oil   9.2825143 -0.165 -0.165 2.835 0.835
> 34      US        B Edible Oil  32.7455557 -0.165 -0.165 0.835 1.835
> 35  Canada        B Edible Oil   9.0447777 -0.165 -0.165 1.835 1.835
> 36  Mexico        B Edible Oil  21.5822081 -0.165 -0.165 2.835 1.835
> 37      US        C Edible Oil   2.3906442 -0.165 -0.165 0.835 2.835
> 38  Canada        C Edible Oil  25.2536855 -0.165 -0.165 1.835 2.835
> 39  Mexico        C Edible Oil   5.0618632 -0.165 -0.165 2.835 2.835
> 40      US        D Edible Oil  41.0292115 -0.165 -0.165 0.835 3.835
> 41  Canada        D Edible Oil   8.4515698 -0.165 -0.165 1.835 3.835
> 42  Mexico        D Edible Oil  11.9080938 -0.165 -0.165 2.835 3.835
> 43      US        E Edible Oil  42.2518838 -0.165 -0.165 0.835 4.835
> 44  Canada        E Edible Oil  25.6458033 -0.165 -0.165 1.835 4.835
> 45  Mexico        E Edible Oil -19.3037443 -0.165 -0.165 2.835 4.835
> 46      US        A        LPG  25.8891215  0.165 -0.165 1.165 0.835
> 47  Canada        A        LPG  -3.1028641  0.165 -0.165 2.165 0.835
> 48  Mexico        A        LPG  47.5884154  0.165 -0.165 3.165 0.835
> 49      US        B        LPG  11.3000701  0.165 -0.165 1.165 1.835
> 50  Canada        B        LPG  26.8041755  0.165 -0.165 2.165 1.835
> 51  Mexico        B        LPG -13.0209453  0.165 -0.165 3.165 1.835
> 52      US        C        LPG  -5.5292231  0.165 -0.165 1.165 2.835
> 53  Canada        C        LPG  46.3101034  0.165 -0.165 2.165 2.835
> 54  Mexico        C        LPG  19.7622448  0.165 -0.165 3.165 2.835
> 55      US        D        LPG   8.5258791  0.165 -0.165 1.165 3.835
> 56  Canada        D        LPG  20.5856857  0.165 -0.165 2.165 3.835
> 57  Mexico        D        LPG -10.7589733  0.165 -0.165 3.165 3.835
> 58      US        E        LPG  14.8577291  0.165 -0.165 1.165 4.835
> 59  Canada        E        LPG  -6.9590007  0.165 -0.165 2.165 4.835
> 60  Mexico        E        LPG  -3.1651872  0.165 -0.165 3.165 4.835
> ```

```
fake.df.adj %>% 
  ggplot(aes(xpos, ypos, fill = value)) + 
  geom_tile(height = 0.33, width = 0.33) +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(value, 1), "%"),
                color = value < 30), show.legend = F) +
  geom_text(data = fake.df.adj %>% filter(Country == "Mexico", segments == "E"),
            aes(label = variable, 
                y = ypos + 1.75*yadj), 
            fontface = "bold") +
  scale_fill_gradient2(labels = function(breaks) paste0(breaks, "%")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("FALSE" = "white", "TRUE" = "black")) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:3, name = NULL,
                     labels = levels(fake.df$Country)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = 1:5, name = "Segments",
                     labels = levels(fake.df$segments)) +
  theme_classic()
```

Now you can plot using `geom_tile`, setting the height and width of the tiles to be 0.33.

I added the labels on top of each tile, rounded to one decimal place, with a % sign. In order to make them show up nicely against the dark background fill for high values, I made the color aesthetic for the labels a logical expression, then further down mapped those values to black and white.

Then there's no way to tell which of the four types of `variable` are in which tile, so I labeled the ones in the upper right corner by filtering the data to only Mexico and E, and shifting the y position a little bit further than the center of the tile using the same adjustment value as before.

Then I added a diverging fill palette and labeled the colourbar with % signs.

Then you have to specify the labels for the x and y scales, since they're just numeric positions right now.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Brian.. Appreciate your help, Accepted as answer :-)