# How to create a heatmap where each cell is divided into 4 triangles?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, heatmap

I would like to divide one cell into one separate heatmap/with multiple color codes.

Each square is divided into 4 triangles and each triangle has its own numerical value/color code.
[image: You can see an example here.]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is an example creating triangles, a bit similar to [Python package to plot two heatmaps in one (split each square into two triangles)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63530701/python-package-to-plot-two-heatmaps-in-one-split-each-square-into-two-triangles/63531813#63531813).
Many variations and refinements are possible. **[Update: separating into functions and dataframe example]**

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.tri import Triangulation
import numpy as np

def create_demo_data(M, N):
    # create some demo data for North, East, South, West
    # note that each of the 4 arrays can be either 2D (N by M) or 1D (N*M)
    # M columns and N rows
    valuesN = np.repeat(np.abs(np.sin(np.arange(N))), M)
    valuesE = np.arange(M * N) / (N * M)
    valuesS = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (N, M))
    valuesW = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (N, M))
    return [valuesN, valuesE, valuesS, valuesW]

def triangulation_for_triheatmap(M, N):
    xv, yv = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-0.5, M), np.arange(-0.5, N))  # vertices of the little squares
    xc, yc = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0, M), np.arange(0, N))  # centers of the little squares
    x = np.concatenate([xv.ravel(), xc.ravel()])
    y = np.concatenate([yv.ravel(), yc.ravel()])
    cstart = (M + 1) * (N + 1)  # indices of the centers

    trianglesN = [(i + j * (M + 1), i + 1 + j * (M + 1), cstart + i + j * M)
                  for j in range(N) for i in range(M)]
    trianglesE = [(i + 1 + j * (M + 1), i + 1 + (j + 1) * (M + 1), cstart + i + j * M)
                  for j in range(N) for i in range(M)]
    trianglesS = [(i + 1 + (j + 1) * (M + 1), i + (j + 1) * (M + 1), cstart + i + j * M)
                  for j in range(N) for i in range(M)]
    trianglesW = [(i + (j + 1) * (M + 1), i + j * (M + 1), cstart + i + j * M)
                  for j in range(N) for i in range(M)]
    return [Triangulation(x, y, triangles) for triangles in [trianglesN, trianglesE, trianglesS, trianglesW]]

M, N = 5, 4  # e.g. 5 columns, 4 rows
values = create_demo_data(M, N)
triangul = triangulation_for_triheatmap(M, N)
cmaps = ['Blues', 'Greens', 'Purples', 'Reds']  # ['winter', 'spring', 'summer', 'autumn']
norms = [plt.Normalize(-0.5, 1) for _ in range(4)]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
imgs = [ax.tripcolor(t, np.ravel(val), cmap=cmap, norm=norm, ec='white')
        for t, val, cmap, norm in zip(triangul, values, cmaps, norms)]

ax.set_xticks(range(M))
ax.set_yticks(range(N))
ax.invert_yaxis()
ax.margins(x=0, y=0)
ax.set_aspect('equal', 'box')  # square cells
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Here is a variation for the same data, with text added to the sub cells:

```py
imgs = [ax.tripcolor(t, val.ravel(), cmap='RdYlGn', vmin=0, vmax=1, ec='white')
        for t, val in zip(triangul, values)]
for val, dir in zip(values, [(-1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (0, -1)]):
    for i in range(M):
        for j in range(N):
            v = val[j, i]
            ax.text(i + 0.3 * dir[1], j + 0.3 * dir[0], f'{v:.2f}', color='k' if 0.2 < v < 0.8 else 'w', ha='center', va='center')
cbar = fig.colorbar(imgs[0], ax=ax)
```

[image: with text added]

To work with a dataframe, `pd.pivot_table()` can be used. Note that empty cells will just end up empty in the final plot (showing the white background color). Fully empty rows and columns will be left out automatically.

```py
import pandas as pd

days = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri']
df = pd.DataFrame({'cols': np.random.choice([*'abcdefghij'], 40),
                   'rows': np.random.choice(days, 40),
                   'north': np.random.rand(40),
                   'east': np.random.rand(40),
                   'south': np.random.rand(40),
                   'west': np.random.rand(40)})
df['rows'] = pd.Categorical(df['rows'], categories=days)  # fix an ordering
df_piv = df.pivot_table(index='rows', columns='cols')
M = len(df_piv.columns) // 4
N = len(df_piv)
values = [df_piv[dir] for dir in
          ['north', 'east', 'south', 'west']]  # these are the 4 column names in df

triangul = triangulation_for_triheatmap(M, N)
cmaps = ['RdYlBu'] * 4
norms = [plt.Normalize(0, 1) for _ in range(4)]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 4))
imgs = [ax.tripcolor(t, np.ravel(val), cmap=cmap, norm=norm, ec='white')
        for t, val, cmap, norm in zip(triangul, values, cmaps, norms)]

ax.tick_params(length=0)
ax.set_xticks(range(M))
ax.set_xticklabels(df_piv['north'].columns)
ax.set_yticks(range(N))
ax.set_yticklabels(df_piv.index)
ax.invert_yaxis()
ax.margins(x=0, y=0)
ax.set_aspect('equal', 'box')  # square cells
plt.colorbar(imgs[0], ax=ax)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: triangular heatmap from dataframe]

PS: Here is a possible way to create a heatmap divided into 4 squares. White grid lines can be used to draw the separations.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

M, N = 5, 4
values = np.random.uniform(0, 100, (N * 2, M * 2))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(values, extent=[-0.5, M - 0.5, N - 0.5, -0.5], cmap='viridis')

ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0, M))
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(-0.5, M), minor=True)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0, N))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(-0.5, N), minor=True)
ax.grid(which='minor', lw=4, color='white', clip_on=False)
ax.grid(which='major', lw=2, color='white', clip_on=False)
ax.tick_params(length=0)
for s in ax.spines:
    ax.spines[s].set_visible(False)
plt.show()
```

[image: example of separation into 4 square subcells]

Comment: Thank you very much @JohanC! it works! I will mark it as answered and one more question: do you know by any chance, how one can one split the cells using squares instead of triangles using PYTHON? like in this post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45798250/divide-one-cell-into-one-separate-heatmap-with-multiple-color-code

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230569/discussion-between-berk-and-johanc).

Comment: @Berk I updated the answer separating the function that calculates the triangle geometry and added an example of how a dataframe could be used.  Please delete the old comments, as they make it hard for other people to know what's going on.

Comment: Thanks, but NaN values are drawn the same color as the minimum values.

Comment: Are you using the latest matplotlib?  Are you using a special colormap?  Are your values integers or floats? It's hard to understand what you mean with "it reads the Nan". Could you create a new question, with a simple test dataframe (containing e.g. 2 rows/columns and some NaNs)?  Also add the code as you are using it, together with the generated output. And indicate what you need differently.

Comment: Yes it's the latest version (3.) I use "jet". The values are in floats. But the Nan values are considered as the min values.

Comment: Latest version is 3.3.4, you might want to upgrade as there are recent changes. Better also upgrade pandas.  "jet" is [not recommended here](http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2014/10/16/how-bad-is-your-colormap/) because of the yellow highlight at the wrong spot, but the behavior with nan is the same for all standard color maps.  You could try `my_cmap = plt.get_cmap('jet')` and `my_cmap .set_bad('none')`. The latest version gives a deprecation warning for `set_bad`.  If you get an error `object has no attribute 'set_bad'` you really need to upgrade.

Comment: I generated a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66888448/how-to-exclude-nan-values-on-a-plot