# How to exclude Nan values on a plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

My data has Nan values but when I generate a plot the Nan values are considered as min values. I want those values are not shown on the plot.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt    
from matplotlib.tri import Triangulation    
import numpy as np    
    
M, N = 11, 1             
valuesN = np.array([       np.nan,        np.nan, 0.03572389, 0.884389, 0.5,         0.912367,
         0.898027, 0.35744717, 0.42150131,        np.nan,        np.nan ])        
valuesE = np.array([       np.nan,        np.nan, 0.03572389, 0.02884389, 0.2,         0.312367,
         0.55898027, 0.45744717, 0.62150131,        np.nan,        np.nan ])        
valuesS = np.array([       np.nan,        np.nan, 0.63572389, 0.02884389, 0.1,         0.14512367,
         0.998027, 0.45744717, 0.62150131,        np.nan,        np.nan ])        
valuesW = np.array([       np.nan,        np.nan, 0.03572389, 0.02884389, 0.,         0.612367,
         0.598027, 0.15744717, 0.90131,        np.nan,        np.nan ])
    
values = [valuesN, valuesE, valuesS, valuesW]            
xv, yv = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-0.5, M), np.arange(-0.5, N))# vertices of the little squares     
xc, yc = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0, M), np.arange(0, N))  # centers of the little squares    
x = np.concatenate([xv.ravel(), xc.ravel()])    
y = np.concatenate([yv.ravel(), yc.ravel()])            
cstart = (M + 1) * (N + 1)  # indices of the centers            
trianglesN = [(i + j * (M + 1), i + 1 + j * (M + 1), cstart + i + j * M) for j in range(N) for i in range(M)]    
trianglesE = [(i + 1 + j * (M + 1), i + 1 + (j + 1) * (M + 1), cstart + i + j * M) for j in range(N) for i in range(M)]    
trianglesS = [(i + 1 + (j + 1) * (M + 1), i + (j + 1) * (M + 1), cstart + i + j * M) for j in range(N) for i in   range(M)]    
trianglesW = [(i + (j + 1) * (M + 1), i + j * (M + 1), cstart + i + j * M) for j in range(N) for i in range(M)]    
triangul = [Triangulation(x, y, triangles) for triangles in [trianglesN, trianglesE, trianglesS, trianglesW]]           
        
fig, ax = plt.subplots()                
        
imgs = [ax.tripcolor(t, val.ravel(), cmap="jet", vmin=0, vmax=1, ec='white' )
                 for t, val in zip(triangul, values)]     
    
cbar = fig.colorbar(imgs[0], ax=ax)       
    
ax.invert_yaxis()
ax.margins(x=0, y=0)
ax.set_aspect('equal', 'box')  # square cells
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show
```

I get a plot below, as shown the Nan values are like min values. : [image],

Comment: On Matplotlib version 3.3.4, cannot replicate the issue.

Comment: I use the version 3.1.1.

Comment: Well, people have been working very hard to improve matplotlib. There were 8785 commits since that version. Meanwhile you might use `my_cmap = plt.get_cmap('Spectral'); my_cmap.set_bad('#FFFFFF00'); my_cmap.set_under('#FFFFFF00')` and then `ax.tripcolor(..., cmap=my_cmap)`

Comment: Does the comment solve your problem?  (`'#FFFFFF00'` is fully transparent white. `set_under()` sets the color for values lower than `vmin`. `set_bad` sets the color for NaN and infinitive values. It seems the old matplotlib version doesn't support a bad color nor the transparency for the under color, resulting in white without transparency. Note that a color of `'none'` would be fully transparent black, which is the default bad color in the current version.)

Comment: Thanks, it works nicely.